# Are Django querysets really lazy when using Paginator?

Tags: python, django

I wrote a view with pagination and multiple querysets.
How ever, as I'm using namedtupled, sorted() and chain() method before actually using pagination, I was asking myself if my queries could be interpreted **before** I actually use Paginator.

In that case, my code would be dummy: pagination would seemed to work as expected but performances would be awful. (I can't check it now since I have a powerful computer and few data).

Could you tell me in that case if everything is ok and queries are **NOT** executed before pagination occurs?

```
scan_evts = [ScanEventTuple(
    evt_id=e.pk,
    date=e.created) \
    for e in ScanEvent.get_scan_events(shop=shop_to_check) \
             .order_by('-created')]

userewards_evts = [UseRewardEventTuple(
    evt_id=e.pk,
    date=e.created) \
    for e in UseRewardEvent.get_usereward_events(shop=shop_to_check) \
             .order_by('-created')]

redeemdeals_evts = [RedeemDealsEventTuple(
    dr_id=e.pk,
    date=e.redeem_date) \
    for e in DealRecipients.get_redeem_events(shop=shop_to_check) \
             .order_by('-redeem_date')]

event_list = sorted(
    chain(scan_evts, userewards_evts, redeemdeals_evts),
    key=attrgetter('date'),
    reverse=True)

# Pagination
paginator = Paginator(event_list, 20)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    all_events = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger: # Mauvaise parametre
    all_events = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage: # Page out of range
    all_events = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Comment: It doesn't address the question, but are you aware of Python's style guide?

Comment: Hahaha! Generally yes, but in that case, there are probably improvments to do. (for my defense, pylint found no PEP warning with this syntax ;) )

Answer (score 3):

Your query sets are not lazily evaluated here. As soon as you iterate over them (as for example in `for e in ScanEvent.get...`), the full query set is evaluated. See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

I do not think you're going to be able to paginate over three different query sets without evaluating them.

Comment: Arf! This is what I was afraid of :( But my optimism make me think there is a way to do it... Let's see if someone propose a genius idea.

Comment: It's tough, because behind the scenes pagination uses `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` similar to slicing a queryset. You could do something complicated like keep the last offset value of each of your querysets in the URI and then fetch the next 20 of each event, sort those 60, and then find the new effective offsets, but it's going to be more of a pain than just using the paginator.